# Sharepoint API to Upload Files and copy to Ms teams

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to add files to SharePoint and then need to copy these uploaded files to Microsoft Teams File Tab

Anyone can help me here that what steps I need to follow to create files and then copy to Files Tab of Ms teams.

I was looking at MS Graph API but did not get an idea about it.

Anyone can help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking this [File tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv19d.png)?

If so, MS Teams actually store those files in a SharePoint Document Library. If you copy file to the corresponding library, it will appear in File tab.

Thanks